# Why does CGFloat.zero exist?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

Is there a particular reason why Apple [defined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/3126532-zero) `CGFloat.zero`? When should we use it? And how is it different from `0`?

Comment: 1) Consider the value is **not** `0` (an integer), and a direct replacement in some contexts would lead to incorrect results; 2) See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/3127690-zero — so putting these two together there is a nice argument for code styling and explicitness. Neither “needs” to be used.

Comment: One big difference is that `0` is not a CGFloat.

Comment: @Scrrr is it okay if I edit the question such that it "can be answered with facts and citations"? Then it can be reopened again.

Comment: @BartvanKuik yes of course!

Answer (score 9):

Generic algorithms are built on top of protocols which let us write common code that can apply to many types. The [AdditiveArithmetic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic) protocol requires that conforming types have a zero value (`.zero`) which can be used for algorithms that require that. With that, you can write a single function that can work with the many different kinds of integers (Int16, Int32, Int…), floats (Double, Float, CGFloat…), and even vectors. Anything that has an arithmetic zero, the concept of "adding and subtracting," and can be equated (since AdditiveArithmetic requires Equatable), can participate.

AdditiveArithmetic does not require that a type conform to  ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, which means that it may not be possible create the type using the `0` symbol. Vector types typically are not initialized this way, but still have a "zero value."

As an example of how you can use this, consider `sum()`, which can work on integers, floats, vectors, or any custom type you would like to make that conforms to AdditiveArithmetic:

```
extension Sequence where Element: AdditiveArithmetic {
    func sum() -> Element {
        reduce(.zero, +)
    }
}
```